# Create and send an envelope from a template in docusign restapi v2.1 issue

Tags: docusignapi

I have created postman request to create and send envelop from template.
After sending it's returning this error

```
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.
```

Here is my postman request data

```
URL:https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xxxxxxxx/envelopes
Method: POST
Body:
{
    "templateId":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email":"test@gmail.com",
            "name":"Tester",
            "roleName":"signer3"
        } 
    ],
    "status":"sent"
}
```

What can be the issue?
Here is the documentation [link](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-template-remote/)

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong above. You can see the full [How to send an envelope with a template article](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-template-remote).

Please confirm your accountId is correct where you have xxxxxxxx.

Please also see if you can use any URL for API calls.

Comment: I have referred this article.Seems it's c# sdk issue.I have used RESTAPIs then problem resolved.And this article bash scripts also not working, it return invalid url error.

Comment: No errors.Assume there are 2 recipients to I need to send sign request emails.
I using same template.Which is created in docusign site.Then I have sent both recipients to emails.If one recipient finish his request through email, after another recipients to display that view as designer view not a preview one

Answer (score 1):

A 400 error indicates there was something going on with the request. Can you turn on your API logging and see if you can reproduce the error? I agree with Inbar, I don't immediately see anything out of alignment. https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

If you could send the resulting log file along with a copy of your template to matt.king@docusign.com we can have a closer look.